# Tomcat - NoClassDefFoundError when deploy war to remote tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

In my local, My web project needs asm-3.3.1.jar. If i write it in pom.xml, it didn't works. But if i put asm to tomcat/lib folder, everything looks perfect and i can access my services.

Now, i deployed my project to remote tomcat on digitalocean. I copied asm-3.3.1.jar to remote tomcat/lib folder. I can see that smoothly.But when i try to access the my project, i get an error as if it does not add the jar to tomcat/lib folder.

I looked everywhere I could find, but I could not find a solution.

I add some screenshots about the project below:

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>story</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.3-606.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My remote tomcat's lib folder. You can see asm jar here.
[image]

The contents of the war file i deployed:
[image]

Tomcat catalina.log (looks fine) :

```
10-Sep-2018 17:21:06.914 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-38] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
10-Sep-2018 17:21:50.654 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-40] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
10-Sep-2018 17:21:51.391 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-35] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
10-Sep-2018 17:21:52.047 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-36] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
10-Sep-2018 17:22:34.963 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-39] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
10-Sep-2018 17:54:12.144 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-42] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/sove] has started
10-Sep-2018 17:54:12.676 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-42] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were $
10-Sep-2018 17:54:12.705 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-42] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
10-Sep-2018 17:54:12.733 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-42] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/sove] is completed
10-Sep-2018 17:54:38.531 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-43] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sove.service
```

This is error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.33
```

Any ideas ?
Thank you.
sfmbe.

Comment: List down all the jars used in this project related to jersey and edit your question

Comment: I edited @NIKETBHANDARY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I found problem. I had asm jar in tomcat lib folder as i said. When i execute project in my local, project takes asm classes from tomcat. But if i deploy project to tomcat in remote server, it can't take classes anywhere.

So i removed jar from tomcat. Then i added asm dependency in pom.xml. After maven install, i added jar to project source. (Right click project-properties-deployment assembly-add-java build path entries- maven dependencies.)

I hope this is helpfull for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't have the same JAR in tomcat/lib and in a war file. You can setup provided dependency in pom.xml when you've placed the asm jar in libs.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>asm</groupId>
 <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.1</version> 
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Read more on tomcat classloaders  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: i tried your solution in my local. I deleted jar from tomcat/lib and pom.xml. Then i tried your dependency. Now i get error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor" again.

Comment: That dependency removes a particular jar from the result war file, so it expects having that jar in your tomcat/lib. Please try to keep in tomcat/lib and  rebuild war with scope provided.

Comment: unfortunately still same error. "http://188.166.30.200:8080/sove/GetStories/getStoryList/true/1/a"

Comment: My wild guess is ASM version ja JERSEY dependency does not like each other. You could try update jersey and/or asm...or downgrade. Also do you have `gson-x-x.jar` two times in war file?

Comment: I updated all jar to newest version. But it doesn't work. And also i deleted one of gson jars but is this a problem?